# Difference in file size of an Excel file when downloading directly as opposed to open and saving it

Tags: compression, excel-2007, openxml

May be the title of my question is really awful but I couldn't figure a better way to frame it. So the problem is I have a Silverlight web app that does some processing and generates an Excel file as output. THe Excel generation code uses OpenXML format to create various XML parts and packages and using System.Packaging.CompressionOptions I compress the file generated. Now, when the browser (IE 9) shows a download options box, if I click Open to open the file in Excel and then do a SaveAs, it saves the file with a further reduced size as opposed to if I hit Save directly on the download box in which case it saves it with whatever size the file was created with.

Any ideas why these 2 ways of saving the same file result in different sizes?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you used the OpenXML library, there might be some inefficiencies or errors. Resaving the file in Excel will fix any duplicate formatting, update the metadata (possibly reducing it) and fix any validation errors. I encourage getting the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool provided with the OpenXML SDK to check for any validation errors and to better understand where more inefficiencies might lie. It is possible to automatically resave the file using Excel by using Interop (using C# anyways).

Comment: thanks for your reply, i m not sure however if it answers my question. But anyway, I am gonna look into making the generated file more Excel like.